# mysql replication to read replica fail

Tags: mysql

I have mysql, with read replica.

**The column table as follow:**

```
ID: integer
Value: integer
```

**SQL binlog that fails**

```
insert into `table` (id, value) VALUES (1, '');
```

**Replication fail** due to

```
Error 'Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'value' at row 1' on query.
```

Both the table has sql mode of **STRICT_TRANS_TABLES**

Why is `insert into table (id, value) VALUES (1, '')` is being replay in replica since it is error insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Statements are never written to the binary log unless they succeeded on the source instance. Somehow that statement was valid on the source.

The sql_mode is strict by default, but any session can override the sql_mode. You should check your application code. I've even seen some app frameworks that changed the sql_mode without the developer's knowledge.

It could be that the `value` column is a varchar type on the source, but a numeric type on the replica. This is unlikely, but possible, so you should double-check that.

A good way to prevent the error is to use ROW-based replication. Then the binary log will not contain SQL statements, it will contain row images, i.e. the result of the insert, not the insert syntax. The [binlog_format](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_binlog_format) is ROW by default on MySQL 8.0, so I assume you have configuration to change this to MIXED or STATEMENT.